# Onclick javascript Quotation mark - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

When the variable have quotation marks or single quotes the function doesn't work.

Code:

```
<a onclick="javascript:return OpenModal('<%# GeraLog(Eval("loe_id")) %>')" style="cursor:   pointer"> <img src="../Imagens/Visualizar.png" alt="Descrição" /></a>
```

Comment: Show us the rendered HTML. And define "doesn't work" better. Do you get a specific js error?

Comment: Appears the code: ' + ")" style="cursor: pointer"> in my page.

Answer (score 2):

Try using string concatenation to resolve nested quotes conflict.

```
<a onclick='<%# "javascript:return OpenModal(" + GeraLog(Eval("loe_id")) + ");" %>'  style="cursor:   pointer"> <img src="../Imagens/Visualizar.png" alt="Descrição" /></a>
```

Comment: Adil, your code solved the problem with quotation marks, but with single quotes the problem persists. Like 'text'. Thank You

Comment: Updated my answer, check if it helps?

Comment: The problem is the same: "text" works, 'text' don't. And I noticed that the IE show the error in the botton: Mensagem: Invalid character
Line: 94, Character: 18, Código: 0...

Comment: The function OpenModal stop working after using your code. But the code: ' + ")" style="cursor: pointer"> that appeared next the image doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! I kept my code:

```
<a onclick="javascript:return OpenModal('<%# GeraLog(Eval("loe_id")) %>')" style="cursor:   pointer"> <img src="../Imagens/Visualizar.png" alt="Descrição" /></a>
```

In my code behind I used:

```
public string GeraLog(object loe_id)
    {
        tab_log tabLog = new tab_log { Tab_usuarios = { usu_id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlUsuario.SelectedValue) } };

        DateTime? Nulo = null;

        tabLog.log_data_inicio = txtPeriodoDe.Text == string.Empty ? Nulo : DateTime.Parse(txtPeriodoDe.Text);
        tabLog.log_data_final = txtPeriodoAte.Text == string.Empty ? Nulo : DateTime.Parse(txtPeriodoAte.Text);
        tabLog.Tab_usuarios.usu_id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlUsuario.SelectedValue);
        tabLog.loe_id = (int)loe_id;

        string tabela = ddlModulos.SelectedValue;

        DataTable table = tabLog.SelectLogModal(tabLog, tabela);

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("O usuário: ");
            sb.Append(row["quem_alterou"]);
            sb.Append(" alterou o campo ");
            sb.Append(row["campo_alterado"]);
            sb.Append(" de ");
            sb.Append(row["valor_anterior"].ToString().Replace("\"", "&quot").Replace("\'", "&lsquo;"));
            sb.Append(" para ");
            sb.Append(row["valor_atual"].ToString().Replace("\"", "&quot").Replace("\'", "&lsquo;"));
            sb.Append(" | ");
            sb.Append(row["data"]);
            sb.Append(" - ");
            sb.Append(row["hora"]);
            sb.Append("<br>");
        }

        loe_id = sb;

        if (loe_id.ToString() == "")
        {
            loe_id = "Nenhuma informação alterada";
        }

        return loe_id.ToString();
    }
```

Thank you guys.